# Is there a way to exclude {ignore-on-commit} changes from TortoiseSVN Explorer icon decorations?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, explorer

TortoiseSVN shows icon decorations in Windows Explorer which show whether there are any uncommitted changes in a particular directory tree.  For example:

[image: TortoiseSVN icon decoration]

The above image shows that somewhere in the directory tree of `Trunk` there is a changed file.

However, I often use the `ignore-on-commit` changelist to hold changes which I never want to commit - for example `Web.config` changes related to connection strings.

I cannot rely on the icon decorations letting me know whether I have changes, as they will also show up with a red (!) even if there's only `Web.config` changes.  This adds unnecessary noise to Explorer.

Is there a way to change this so that only changes I *want* to commit are flagged as changes in Explorer?

Comment: Why don't you use 'svn:ignore' property? See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Comment: @bahrep - The files I want to ignore are versioned files, which cannot be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently upgraded to [TortoiseSVN version 1.8.3](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) (I was using 1.7.x before) and it appears that there is now an option to do exactly this!  It works perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to change this

No. Icon overlays work

- for **all** files
- by the **same** manner
- **always**